# Amazon AWS in browser security and alternatives

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, cross-browser, amazon-dynamodb

I am building an application which is going to use AWS's services like S3, DynamoDB, and SNS (plus the obvious others). What I had in my mind was, that we can directly connect the browser with these services and skip the need for a proxy server that I would have otherwise used to map between the client and these services. My concerns are:

- The client  (browser), will get to know that the data source / services used is Amazon AWS, and further, if not configured properly,
  can open doors for unwanted intruders.
- Not all browsers are expected to be ready for CORS
- using services like DynamoDB, SNS, will extend a little too many details to the clients that needed, like, what all database fields we are using, what kind of data is being entered/read, what notification is sent, etc.
- Authentication provided for AWS browser sdk is dependent upon Facebook, Google, and Amazon, but my requirement may not always need the user to be authenticated, and even if authentication is there, it will not be these providers.

So, with these concerns, my question is, should we have a proxy in between AWS and client, or are there any other secure options available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are looking all the services as one and interaction of those services with client directly. I don't see any a usecase where you would give DynamoDB or RDS as a direct access to your client and need to worry about the vulnerabilities, instead you would essentially build a web application which will running out of an EC2 instance and which would be connecting to the DynamoDB. You would just be issuing an URL through which the client will access the same via browser.

These are the entities which are provided by Amazon to Incorporate / Enforce the Security. You may look into that

- VPC ( for EC2, RDS, DynamoDB, Redshift etc. )
- Security Group ( EC2, RDS, Redshift etc. )
- Bucket Policy  ( S3 )
- ACL ( S3 )
- Subnets, ACLs ( VPC )

The bottom line for your all your questions is to use your custom application as a wrapper which consume all the services and expose only your web application via https.

Comment: Though I am discussing it again after 1 month, but the reason I asked this question was, that imagine, the technologies are evolving, we have CORS for effectively dealing with stuff like remote file upload (browser based), which reduces the server requirement for fileuploads, by directly uploading to S3. The same way, you can put or read entries from the database (DynamoDB). But, here my question was, is it data encryption (browser based) that we can try or some other technique that people around are utilizing.